# Sharing MongoHQ database between Sinatra and Rails applications in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sinatra, mongoid, mongohq

I have a Sinatra and Rails 3 applications. Applications were created independently and are hosted in 2 separate Heroku instances. So I need a share one MongoHQ database to both applications. How can I do it? Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really easy.

In the application that has the MongoHQ database look at the output of `heroku config` - you're looking for the entry `MONGOHQ_URL`.

All you need do is on the other application set a similar config variable to the same value as displayed from the the first application and then use it as ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] in your second application.

Comment: Thanks you for educate me. :) I'm inserted Sinatra application into Rails 3 application. So there's no need to share a database for me.